# implode an array of objects and filter only by one property

Tags: php, smarty

How I'd implode an array of objects and filter only by one property (`category` in my case) ?

The object looks like this:

```
[335] => Array
(
    [category_id] => 335
    [parent_id] => 0
    [category] => Category name
    [aa__aaa00_google_product_category] => 0
)
```

Here's the current smarty code:

```
{foreach from=$categories item=category}
   {'| '|implode:$category}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: As in `$category.category`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Getting `implode(): Invalid arguments passed` if I'd specify as you've mentioned

Comment: No, mine was a (malformed) question as to what you want to obtain. You want all the `category` properties of each element of `$categories` separated by a `|`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Yes, as you've mentioned. All categories separated by | and only categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output each `category` property, then (using `last`) check whether you're at the last element of the array. If you're not, output a `|`, otherwise output nothing.

```
{foreach from=$categories item=category name=cat}
  {$category.category}{if $smarty.foreach.cat.last}{else}|{/if}
{/foreach}
```